# Firebase Robo test doesn't work in a custom chrome tab

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-test-lab

I am using Firebase Test Lab to do automated testing for my app.
I created robo script from Android studio, in which there is a sign in page which uses chrome custom tab.
When I execute the script, it fails on the chrome custom tab.
Is there a way to fix it[image]

Answer (score 0):

Robo doesn't do anything with external apps or web content.  It needs to stay within the confinement of a single app, and it can only script with native UI elements.

Comment: So if I have sign in page wiht chrom custom tab, then there is no way for me to get in ?

Comment: Also I see the custom view action is not recorded as well